# Archive retrieval from AWS Glacier

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I uploaded an archive to AWS glacier using boto3 using the code as described here:
https://github.com/tbumi/glacier-upload/blob/develop/main.py

It returned me archive id which **I didn't save at the time** and i went through the AWS documentation and archive id is needed for archive retrieval.

As i understood from the boto3 documentation, You first need to create a job as follows:

```
job = archive.initiate_archive_retrieval()
```

This returns me a glacier.Job Object and which contains many attributes such as Job id etc.
Then i can use the

```
response = job.get_output(
    range='string'
)
```

To download the archive from glacier after notified via SNS after 3-5hrs after the job has been completed and the range being the part of the archive in bytes to download( defaults to whole archive).

Also i am not able to delete the vault as the vault is not empty and requires me to delete the archive which again needs the archive id for doing so.

I also looked at their REST API which again is dependent on the archive id for deletion.
Here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-vault-delete.html

Also i found that downloading archives can only be done programtically either using their REST APIS or SDK's or aws-cli therefore shutting the door to do so using the AWS console.

Since i don't have the archive id, is it possible for me to retrieve the archive using any other method? If not, is it possible to delete the vault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the IDs by running a vault inventory.

> ...you can use Initiate a Job (POST jobs) to initiate a new inventory
>   retrieval for a vault. The inventory contains the archive IDs you use
>   to delete archives using Delete Archive (DELETE archive) .
>   http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/glacier.html

So just use `Client.initiate_job` with `Type` set to `inventory-retrieval`, and you'll get your ID after the inventory finishes.
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/glacier.html#Glacier.Client.initiate_job

Comment: So i need to make an inventory request and also will provide SNSTopic as a parameter to receive the notification upon inventory finish.
The initiate_job() returns a job id which i can save into some DB and using this later(By later i mean any time of day) can download the inventory.
Sounds about right?

Comment: Yes. You initiate inventory, wait for it to complete, then read the archives list.